# How to discard check-out for a document using powershell in MOSS-2007?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2007

I am able to check out and chek in the document but can't find any cmdlet or function in order to discard check-out on the document.
Please suggest if you can.

Answer (score 1):

`UndoCheckOut()` is  the method required. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.undocheckout%28v=office.12%29.aspx)